# Does AngularJS ngView works inside a Chrome App?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, ng-view

I did my research and it's still not clear to me. It seems it once did, when Chrome Apps were still called Chrome Packaged Apps.

Is it navigation a no-no for Chrome Apps? It doesn't sound right to me. The use of views seems the way to go...

Trying to use ngView I got the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load chrome-extension://opjofdlbcghpdgfhmpdfmadlnmnblijo/views/main.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

The error persists even using:

`$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);`

(this line is in an related answer, I'll try to get the link here later)

Inline templates don't do it either. Apparently.

So, I'm looking for up-to-date info on this subject. The following article is great: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/chrome-apps-on-angular.html. But the code available on Github is not so complete as stated so I had a little trouble trying to test it.

Of course it's possible do go with ngHide, ngShow, ngIf etc... But having templates in seprate files is much much better...

Comment: Each Chrome App window is a single-page app (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: @sowbug So? The first characteristic in the link you pointed is: "Chunking – the web page is constructed by loading **chunks of HTML fragments** and JSON data instead of receiving full HTML from a web server on every request. (Backbone.js, pjax, jQuery, Upshot.js)". That's what ngView and ngInclude are for, right?